# list of events for ngModel in two-way data binding

Tags: angular, ngmodel, two-way-binding

In two-way data binding using `ngModel`

```
<input [(ngModel)]="this.name" >
```

is actually

```
<input [value]="this.name" (input)="this.name=$event.target.value>
```

So `ngModel` internally maps `(input)` event of `<input>` to `this.name`

Where can I find information about the events ngModel generates for other elements like `<p>` etc.?

I want to increase the font of `<p>` when `<p>` is clicked. I could do it without `ngModel` but couldn't do it with `ngModel`

without `ngModel`

```
<p [style.font-size.px]="this.fontsize" (click)="handleParaClick()">Hello {{this.paratext}} {{this.fontsize}}  </p>

  handleParaClick():void{
    this.fontsize+=10;
  }
```

But I couldn't do

```
<p [(style.font-size.px)]="this.fontsize" >Hello {{this.paratext}} {{this.fontsize}}  </p>
```

I am guessing that for `<p>`, either `ngModel` doesnt do anything or does not generate `(click)` event

Comment: I am not sure what you understand by NgModel, and how it helps to click handle in `p`. `[(ngModel)]` is actually `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)`.  What you did without `ngModel` is correct and only way. Unless you create a custom directive.

Comment: I believe (ngModelChange) gets emitted when something changes in DOM. What changes in DOM which causes Angular to emit ngModelChange? I assume that when ngModelChange gets emitted would depend on the element with which we are using ngModel. In 'input' element, it is probably change in value if the input. If it is correct, where can I find for which elements Angular would emit ngModelChange and for which changes?

Comment: No, ngModelChange as suggest  will  be triggered when param assigned to ngModel changes.  Where did you read these concepts ?

Comment: But if only change in param triggers in ngModelChange, then that would be 1-way binding. ngModelChange should also get triggered when some property of HTML element it is assigned to (DOM element) gets changed so that param can be updated. In `<input [value]="this.name" (input)="this.name=$event.target`, change in `name` updates value due to change detection (don't know how this works internally in Angular) and when `value` of `<input>` changes (DOM property change), ngModelChange probably gets triggered.

Comment: Do you agree - `<input [(ngModel)]="this.name" >` is `<input [value]="this.name" (input)="this.name=$event.target.Does Angular convert the first statement into 2nd one automatically? If so, then somewhere is it hardwired that ngModel with `<input>` keeps `value` and property in sync (when property value changes `<input>` `value` gets updated and when `(input)` event happens, property changes? My question is with which other elements can I use ngModel? Can I use it with <li>, <a>? Change event in these elements woudl trigger ngModelChange? Where can I find this information?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts its just 100 line code . Read and ask if you did not understand anything there

Comment: Thanks. I'll take some time to go through this. This is advanced compared to my current knowledge of Angular. At the moment, I can see that ngModel would work for form controls like TextArea, Select and Input. It makes sense as these controls would have 'data' for two-way data binding. My original question about `<p>` doesn't make sense as `<p>`'s data would not change (from UI to affect the model).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<p [ngStyle]="{'font-size': this.fontsize}">...</p>
```

this is not two way data binding but puts dinamically the font-size value that contains variable this.fontsize

Comment: Thanks. My problem is not to implement changing font of paragraph but to understand where I can and cannot use ngModel